# Screen flickering in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ati

I'm running an:

- ACER Aspire M3610
- Intel dual core 2160 1.8 GHz (1200 MHz)
- ATI RS600 (Radeon Xpres 1250)

The problem is:

1. Ocasionally the screen flickers when using Mozilla Firefox
2. The screen flicker ever too much when watching YouTube videos.
3. Dash don't shows the colors correctly and shows a blurry image.

I think I have installed the common, bad and ugly, gstreamer codecs, but maybe there are some others that I have to install. There are too many of them.

Could it be a Flash plug-in problem, gstreamer problem, ATI controlers... or what?.

Answer (score 3):

The user solved this question on their own. I am just posting this to show that the question has been answered until this is removed or self-answered.

I have solved the one remaning problem.

I have installed: Gstreamer complements for ffmpeg. Gstreamer Extra
complements. Gstreamer complements for mms, muse pack, etc. Gstreamer
complements for aac, xvid, etc.

And I have installed: Ubuntu restricted Extras.

Well, it seems that flickering has go out.

But Unity Dash is in the same mod. I can't see it in a good way. It
shows an interference pattern(?).

.............................................

I have solved the Unity Dash problem:

First you have to install the Unity Tweak Tool, and then in the *Search* tab
you have to put *Background blur* at the "off" position.

.............................................

Then I have solved my own problems.

Comment: It's sorta conventional to make answers where you're on behalf of the OP a Community Wiki so no rep is gained for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade

sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```